# Phpstan with gitlab-ci cant find srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml because its in the gitignore?

Tags: symfony, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, phpstan

this is my phpstan.neon

```
  parameters:
  checkMissingIterableValueType: false
  checkGenericClassInNonGenericObjectType: false
  symfony:
        container_xml_path: '%rootDir%/../../../var/cache/dev/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml'
  bootstrap: '%rootDir%/../../../vendor/autoload.php'
```

This is my gitlab-ci snippet

```
commit:
  stage: analysis
  variables:
    APP_ENV: dev
  cache:
    untracked: true
    paths:
     - Source/var/cache/dev/
  before_script:
    - cd Source
    - cp .env.example .env
    - composer install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --classmap-authoritative
  script:
    - composer commit
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

And I get the following error:

```
In XmlServiceMapFactory.php line 29:

   [PHPStan\Symfony\XmlContainerNotExistsException]                             
   Container /builds/Mehlichmeyer/heracles-mvp-symfony/Source/vendor/phpstan/p  
   hpstan/../../../var/cache/dev/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml does not e  
   xist
```

The issue is that my gitlab-ci container doesn't have the srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml, since it's in my .gitignore (/var/ is). Any Ideas for a workaround?

Comment: If that container file does not exist, why not build it through `bin/console cache:clear`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I finally found the Issue. I updated my Symfony from 4.x to 5.x, and I had to adjust my phpstan.neon

```
container_xml_path: '%rootDir%/../../../var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml'
```

Locally this never threw an error because I hadn't run bin/console cache:clear, so the old container_xml_path was working fine.

Comment: not sure why this downvoted, probaly author forgot to mention if we just upgrade Symfony version. This solution work for me.

Answer (score 4):

To have this file you must generate the cache for the dev environment with the debug activated. I guess it could be done in the "before_script" section:

```
before_script:
    - cd Source
    - cp .env.example .env
    - composer install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --classmap-authoritative
    - php bin/console cache:warmup --env=dev
```

Your `.env` file must have the debug flag:

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_DEBUG=1
APP_SECRET=APP_SECRET
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###
```

I don't know gitlab-ci but I did this with github-actions and it works well.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. I am already doing the cache warmup in the composer commit step ```"phpstan": [
            "bin/console cache:warmup --env=dev",
            "vendor/bin/phpstan analyse src/ -c phpstan.neon --level=7 -vvv --no-progress --memory-limit=1G"
        ],
        "csfixer": [
            "vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix"
        ],
        "commit": [
            "@phpstan",
            "@csfixer"
        ]